# Replace contents with contents from another file in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I've a file with some text (8/9 lines) called abc.txt

I'm trying to replace a string called    in pqr.xml with contents from above abc.txt file.

Can any one tell me how to do it?

I was trying with below command:

```
sed -i~ "s/ < /Server>/HERE HOW TO PASTE CONTENTS FROM abc.txt/g" pqr.xml
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in `sed` scripting, but perhaps match the `</Server>` tag and turn on a flag, output the contents from abc.txt, then ignore lines until you get to your second identifier.  Are you committed to using `sed`?

Comment: Can you provide the command? I'm new to linux. Any command is fine with me...if its sed, it'll be good

Comment: What you're asking for requires more than just a command...you're going to need to write a script in your favorite language to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about `sed` but with `awk` you might get what you are trying to achieve.

#### awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
# Loop thru each words in your file

    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 

# When the word is pqr.xml, we read your second file

        if($i~/pqr\.xml/) 
            {
                system("cat file2"); 

# We store the content of the file in a variable and print it

                getline a; 
                printf a; 

# For everything else we just print the word as is

            }else 
                printf $i" ";
                print "";
}
```

#### File1:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
this is my pqr.xml
i want to replace
```

#### File2:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file2
replacement
stuff
from
another
file
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] ./script.awk file
this is my replacement
stuff
from
another
file
i want to replace
```

Comment: @Jaypal...How can I add this script in existing shell script?

Comment: @Mike You can save this script and make it executable and then in your main shell script, right when you are about to make substitution, you can call this script by doing `./script.awk file > newfile`. `./` means the script would be in your current directory. You can place it anywhere you want, just state the path to it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more code than you was after, probably, but here's how i would do it, using perl. Let me know if this is working for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $xmlfile;
my $replacement;

open REPLACEMENT,"<abc.txt" or die "Couldn't open abc.txt: $!";
while (<REPLACEMENT>) { $replacement .= $_ }
close REPLACEMENT;

open XML,"<pqr.xml"  or die "Couldn't open pqr.xml: $!";
while (<IN>) { $xmlfile .= $_ }
close XML;

$xmlfile = s/< \/Server>/$replacement/gxm;

open NEW,">NEW_pqr.xml";
print NEW $xmlfile;
close NEW;
```

If this is something you need to do fairly often, stick it into a file named replace.pl, forexample, and place it in the same directory as the file you want to modify. Then chmod it +x. Then you can call it from your shell script

Comment: @Mike If it was me, i would leave it as a standalone perl script, chmod it +x, and call that from your shellscript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed '\| < /Server>|{ r abc.txt
d; }' pqr.xml
```

Will replace any line containing " < /Server>" with the content of abc.txt.  Replacing a partial line is more difficult with sed.